# SQl Query using multipe tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

> Question: Your task is to display the Playlist and Name of the Playlists that do not contain any track of Latin Genre. Order the result in the ascending order of PlaylistId.

The given tables are here:

[image: The given tables are here]

And here is the code I wrote but its not giving desired output.

```
   select playlist.playlistid, playlist.name
   from playlist
   inner join playlisttrack on playlist.playlistid = playlistrack.playlistid
   inner join track on playlisttrack.trackid = track.trackid
   inner join genre on track.genreid = genre.genreid
   where genre.name <> "Latin"
   order by playlist.playlistid asc;
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking for *homework help* must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) You can find more information on how to ask a homework question in the FAQ: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/2029983)

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: @jarlh I'm using MySql

Comment: @Dale K not its not.

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you correctly, you can use `not exists`:

```
select p.playlistid, p.name 
from playlist p
where not exists (
    select 1
    from playlisttrack pt 
    inner join track t on t.trackid = pt.trackid
    inner join genre g on g.genreid = t.genreid
    where pt.playlistid = p.playlistid and g.name = 'Latin'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT playlistId, name 
FROM Playlist 
WHERE playlistId NOT IN (
                         SELECT pt.playlistId 
                         FROM PlaylistTrack pt 
                         inner join Track t 
                            on  pt.trackId = t.trackId inner 
                         join Genre g 
                            on t.genreId = g.genreId 
                         where g.name = 'Latin'
                        ) 
order by playlistId
```